# JavaScript: Increment Method

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, this, increment

I'm trying to make an `increment` method. This seemingly easy task has stumped me.
An example of what I want:

```
var x=5; 
x.increment(); 
console.log(x); //6
```

What I tried to do:

```
Number.prototype.increment=function(){
    this++; //gave me a parser error
};
```

Comment: `this` is immutable. You'll never be able to mutate `x` without replacing it. Have `increment` return the new value, then `x = x.increment()`

Comment: This is not possible. Numbers are immutable.

Comment: `this` is not an exception to the rule that all arguments in JS are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: You might find the following interesting: [What’s happening in this code with Number objects holding properties and incrementing the number?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38637003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are immutable in javascript. when you do `console.log(this)` you will see it will point to *Number* whose primitive value is `5`(in our case), so you can not change it's value.

What you can do is return incremental value(by doing this + 1) from incremnt and assign it to x like x=x.increment();

```js
Number.prototype.increment = function(){
    return this + 1;
}

var x = 5;

x=x.increment();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Why is return being used on line 3 if it's not being used for anything?

Comment: @BenRivers my mistake(edited the answer), I was experimenting and forgot to add x=

Answer (score 0):

`this` cannot be changed directly. Try this way

```
Number.prototype.increment = function(){
    return this + 1;
}

var x = 5;

x = x.increment(); // x will be 6 here
```

Hope this helps.